# ¿Existen restricciones para dar a conocer el sitio a otras personas en eventos de tecnología?

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

En estos días se llevará a cabo el [flisol](https://flisol.info/) en mi ciudad, entonces quería dar a conocer la comunidad en este evento con una ponencia acerca de conocimiento libre, compartiendo las experiencias de aprendizaje en Stack Overflow.

**¿Existe alguna limitación o restricción para llevar a cabo algo así?**

**¿Se puede usar los logos del sitio libremente?**

**¿Existe alguna información adicional que se pueda compartir?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He comentado el caso con nuestro CM @NicolasChabanovsky y [confirma](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49898792#49898792) que lo que decía en mi comentario es correcto:

> En cuanto al uso de los logos, segun se puede leer [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance), entrarían dentro del "fair use" ya que no les darías un uso comercial.
>
> En cuanto al contenido del sitio, todo lo que los usuarios contribuyen puedes usarlo libremente. Resumiendo, creo que en tu caso no hay ningún problema

De hecho me pide añadir que, si se le avisa con tiempo, podría enviar algunas pegatinas de StackOverflow al evento :)

**Editado**

Como muy certeramente apunta @jachguate en un comentario, el contenido creado por los usuarios en la red StackExchange *tiene licencia de [Creative Commons (atribución)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/es/deed.es). Es decir, puede utilizarse, pero debe realizarse la atribución, que es una condición para el uso*.

Pueden consultarse estos aspectos legales en [esta url (en ingles lamentablemente)](https://stackoverflow.com/legal)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, entonces realizaré la ponencia, sería genial lo de las pegatinas el evento está planificado para el 27 de abril

Comment: @JuanPinzón creo que es poco tiempo la verdad. Pero trata de ponerte en contacto con Nicolas, en su [perfil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile) tienes varias formas de contacto, suele estar en [The terminal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317209/274323) habitualmente tambien.

Comment: Solo añadir que lo que lo que los usuarios contribuyen tiene licencia de Creative Commons (atribución). Es decir, puede utilizarse, pero debe realizarse la atribución, que es una condición para el uso. Hago la aclaración, porque _usar libremente_ puede ser leído como _es de dominio público_, y no es exactamente lo mismo. (lamento salir con esos pequeños detalles, pero los considero importantes). Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate es un detalle ciertamente muy importante, y te agradezco que me lo hayas apuntado. Editaré mi respuesta para reflejarlo. Un saludo